# How Do I Set Multiple Categories for a Podcast?

Tags: itunes, podcasts, xml

I have a podcast that I want to be listed under Religion & Spirituality.  I would like for it to be listed when someone selects Christianity or Spirituality.

I just submitted my podcast with the xml code below.  When the page displayed before submitting it only showed the Spirituality category under Religion & Spirituality, not the Christianity category.

```
<itunes:category text="Religion &amp; Spirituality">
<itunes:category text="Christianity"/>
</itunes:category>
<itunes:category text="Religion &amp; Spirituality">
<itunes:category text="Spirituality"/>
</itunes:category>
```

I could not find any documentation about how to do this.  I thought I might try the following.

```
<itunes:category text="Religion &amp; Spirituality">
<itunes:category text="Christianity"/>
<itunes:category text="Spirituality"/>
</itunes:category>
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second format is the proper one. Even if the iTunes listing only shows one category after the name, it will be searchable under both.

More explanation can be found [here](http://www.jakeludington.com/project_studio/20050704_itunes_custom_rss_tags_-_category.html), or in the [official documentation](http://lists.apple.com/archives/syndication-dev/2005/Nov/msg00002.html#_Toc526931682) and a properly formatted multi-category tag is shown below:

```
<itunes:category text="Technology">
<itunes:category text="Computers" />
<itunes:category text="News" />
</itunes:category>
```

If you want multiple subcategories in different main categories, you would do something like your first example:

```
<itunes:category text="Arts &amp; Entertainment">
    <itunes:category text="Games" />
</itunes:category>
<itunes:category text="Technology">
    <itunes:category text="Computers" />
</itunes:category>
```

Comment: Great.  I will save the documentation.  I did leave the second solution in my XML file.  Hopefully it will update soon after I start adding new episodes.  When I see the change in iTunes I will check your response.  Thanks so much!!